# Saving a tmap with a basemap as an image?

Tags: r, tmap

I have created a map in R using tmap, with a basemap, and want to save it as an image.

Whenever I use tmap_save to save it as a .png, I lose the basemap.

Presumably, this is because the basemap is not visible in plot mode and only in view mode.

Is there a good way of saving the map, with the basemap, as an image?

I have a workaround that involves saving it as HTML first, but it's not a great solution.

Comment: It will be easier for us to help if you provide an example with data that we can access. I have had a similar issue but I ended up using `ggplot` for the plotting and `ggmap` to get a basemap. But I would be interested if it is doable with in `tmap`

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar issue trying to create a static map. I've found the tmaptools::read_osm function seems to solve it for me. Here's a reproducible example of three maps:

- map_a looks good, until you save it
- map_b doesn't look good at all
- map_c looks good, even when saved

Create an example map in interactive view. But in the saved file, the basemap doesn't appear.

```
library(tmaptools) 
library(tmap)
data(metro)

tmap_mode("view")
map_a <- tm_basemap("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") +
  tm_shape(metro) +
  tm_bubbles(size = "pop2020", col = "red") 
map_a
tmap_save(map_a, filename="map_a.png")
```

Try to create a similar map as a plot, but basemap doesn't appear at all, and the red dots float without a map.

```
tmap_mode("plot")
map_b <- tm_basemap("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") +
  tm_shape(metro) +
  tm_bubbles(size = "pop2020", col = "red") 
map_b
tmap_save(map_b, filename="map_b.png")
```

Here is a solution: use read_osm. The basemap appears and can be saved.

```
c_osm <- tmaptools::read_osm(bb(metro), ext = 1.05)
map_c <- tm_shape(c_osm) +
  tm_rgb() +
  tm_shape(metro) + 
  tm_bubbles(size = "pop2020", col = "red") 
map_c
tmap_save(map_c, filename="map_c.png")
```

Comment: I ran the code just now. I ran into an error on the third option, but resolved it by adding a call to "bb" before processing the read_osm. Other than that, the bubbles seemed to render. I also tried the mapshot() option offered in the solution posted by @rm1104, and it worked for me.

Comment: 's last solution is great!

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to save the [tmap object as a leaflet](https://rdrr.io/cran/tmap/man/tmap_leaflet.html) object and then use the `mapshot()` function in [mapview package](https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/reference/mapshot.html) to save it as an image. Below is an example.

```
library(mapview)
#May need this for mapshot to work
#webshot::install_phantomjs()

data("World")

map <- tm_basemap(leaflet::providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) + 
tm_shape(World) + tm_polygons(alpha = 0,border.col = "black", lwd = 2)

lf <- tmap_leaflet(map)
mapshot(lf, file = "world_map.png")
```

Comment: `mapview::mapshot(lf, file = "world_map.png")
Could not load  c:%5CUsers%5CKSER~1%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CTemp%5C4%5CRtmpYFNniB%5Cfile5fc82aa164bf.html
Error in (function (url = NULL, file = "webshot.png", vwidth = 992, vheight = 744,  : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 1`

Comment: I am getting the above error while doing this